# Convert Date to Integer C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code to convert from a date in a `string` to an `integer`

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

typedef long long int llint;

llint stringDate2LLInt(std::string date, std::string format)
{
    std::stringstream ss(date);
    std::tm dt;
    ss >> std::get_time(&dt, format.c_str());
    std::time_t tt = std::mktime(&dt);
    return tt;
}

int main()
{
    std::string date("9/29/2014 17:48");
    std::string format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M");
    std::cout << date << "->" << stringDate2LLInt(date, format) << std::endl;
    std::cout << date << "->" << stringDate2LLInt(date, format) << std::endl;
    std::cout << date << "->" << stringDate2LLInt(date, format) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

however, calling it with the same value for the arguments, i.e. `"9/29/2014 17:48"` and `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"` the result is different each time. Why is this happening?

What I wanted to do is to get the number of miliseconds (or maybe seconds) since `00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970 UTC` for a given `date`. Any way I can do this?

Comment: Try checking for `ss.fail()` - and how do you expect to get accurate seconds it the time doesn't include them?

Comment: Ok, let me check that. Concerning seconds, that's the data I'm getting so I don't know why there are no seconds in there, I don't think is mandatory to convert a time to seconds though.

Comment: Identical each time for me, when I add the required headers and turn `std::String` to `std::string`: 
9/29/2014 17:48->553015820
9/29/2014 17:48->553015820
9/29/2014 17:48->553015820
What's the actual code that fails?

Comment: It is not a copy paste of my code but I extracted the part that is failing. I Actually tried it in VS2013 and it gives correct results but in VS2012 it gives a different result each time.

Comment: Seems `std::get_time` is broken (gcc 4.8.2 does not implement it)

Comment: Weird - that code sample gave me identical results in VS2012

Comment: Uhm ... i dont know if there is a conflict somewhere else then. But it is just that code that is returning different values for me. I will check.